# Elegant way of finding unique string pairs from dictionary values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
    some_list = [
                  {
                     item1:'a', 
                     item2:['1', '2']
                  }, 
                  {
                     item1:'b', 
                     item2:['1', '2']
                  }, 
                  {
                     item1:'a', 
                     item2:['1']
                  }
                ]
```

I would like to get:

['a 1', 'a 2', 'b 1', 'b 2'] where each value from item 1 is paired with value from item 2 for each dictionary, and then only the unique strings are left.

I can think of an obvious way to do it, namely:

1. iterate through the some_list;
2. for each dictionary, get a each['item_1'] and each['item_2']
3. for member of each['item_2'] do each['item_1'] + ' ' + member
4. Now, make the list into a set and I have my unique values

I am wondering if these is a more elegant way to do it using list comprehension.

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: Order does not matter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, then you can easily translate your logic into a set-comprehnsion (and convert to `list` if you'd like):

```
In [1]: some_list = [
   ...:                   {
   ...:                      'item1':'a',
   ...:                      'item2':['1', '2']
   ...:                   },
   ...:                   {
   ...:                      'item1':'b',
   ...:                      'item2':['1', '2']
   ...:                   },
   ...:                   {
   ...:                      'item1':'a',
   ...:                      'item2':['1']
   ...:                   }
   ...:                 ]

In [2]: {f"{d['item1']} {v}" for d in some_list for v in d['item2']}
Out[2]: {'a 1', 'a 2', 'b 1', 'b 2'}
```

Comment: _Python 3. **6**_ + is required.

Comment: @CristiFati yes, of course, you can substitute whatever string-formatting you desire (or must settle for).

Comment: And if order did matter, you could enclose the whole thing in `sorted()`

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(item):
     return [item[item1]+' '+k for k in item[item2]]
res = []
[res.append(fun(i)) for i in some_list if(fun(i)) not in res]
print res
```

this should work

Comment: Good answer. But the condition is to get unique values.

Comment: You should not use list-comprehensions for side-effects. That defeats their entire purpose.

Answer (score 1):

another formatting option, runs back to 2.7

```
sorted(map(' '.join,
           {(d['item1'], v)
            for d in some_list
                for v in d['item2']}))
```

still a 'one-liner' but with decorative line breaks and indentation

inner list comp same as other ans, arrived at independently without seeing it 1st